# How to slice a dataframe column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df like this,

```
Main                        Length
Sri playnig well cricket    5
sri went out                2
Ram is in                   1 
Ram went to UK,US           2
```

I am trying to slice the `df["Main"] based on df["Length"]`

My expected output is,

```
Main                        Length
Sri p                       5
sr                          2
R                           1 
Ra                          2
```

I tried

```
def slicer(row):
    for i in df["Length"]:
        row['Main'].slice(0,i)
    return row

 df.apply(slicer,axis=1)
```

but I am getting, `AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'slice'", 'occurred at index 0')`
 please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with indexing:

```
df['Main'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Main'][:x['Length']], axis=1)
```

Or list comprehension with `zip` if no `NaN`s values:

```
df['Main'] = [a[:b] for a, b in zip(df['Main'], df['Length'])]
```

---

```
print(df)
    Main  Length
0  Sri p       5
1     sr       2
2      R       1
3     Ra       2
```

For more general solution is possible use `if-else`:

```
df['Main'] = [a[:b] if len(a) < b else a for a, b in zip(df['Main'], df['Length'])]
print(df)
                       Main  Length
0  Sri playnig well cricket     100
1              sri went out       2
2                 Ram is in       1
3         Ram went to UK,US       2
```